# Could not Autowired JobLauncherTestUtils in Spring-Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am getting below error while performing a functional test for a step in spring-batch .
Getting below error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
```

Below is the configuration file and Test file used for this.

custom-context.xml file:

```
<batch:job id="custom.entities">
    <batch:step id="entity.processor">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="customReader" writer="customWriter" commit-interval="1" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="customReader" class="com.batch.custom.EntityReader" scope="step">
    <property name="providerId" value="#{jobParameters['providerId']}" />
</bean>

<bean id="customWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:c:/Temp/ledgers-output.txt"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PassThroughLineAggregator" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

CustomJobTest.java file

```
@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

@Autowired
private ItemReader<WatchlistDataSet> reader;

@Test
@DirtiesContext
public void testLaunchJob() throws Exception {

    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("providerId", "cnp_1").toJobParameters();

    JobExecution exec = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("entity.processor", jobParameters);

    assertEquals(BatchStatus.COMPLETED, exec.getStatus());

}

public JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils() {
    return jobLauncherTestUtils;
}

public void setJobLauncherTestUtils(JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils) {
    this.jobLauncherTestUtils = jobLauncherTestUtils;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After some googling found out that a bean definition needs to be specified in the context.xml used for JUnit testing.

```
<bean id="jobLauncherTestUtils" class="org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils" >
    <property name="job" ref="custom.entities"/>
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher"/>
</bean>
```

With above definition I am able to autowire JobLauncherTestUtils.